# conditional probability (discrete case).

Tags: probability

I am not sure if I am doing this right.  We have this table

$$\begin{array}{r:r|rr}   
&         &  X\\\hdashline
&         &  1 & 2\\ \hline
&        0&.12 & .08\\
       Y&1&.48 &.12\\  
        &2&0   &.2
\end{array}$$

And I have to find $\mathsf P(X\geqslant 1.5\mid -0.5\leqslant Y\leqslant 1.5)$
So I did this:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geqslant 1.5\mid -0.5\leqslant Y\leqslant 1.5)=&~\frac{\mathsf P(X=2 \mid ( Y=0\cup Y=1))}{\mathsf P(Y=0\cup Y=1)}\\[1ex]=&~\frac{0.2}{0.8}\\[1ex]=&~0.25\end{align}$$

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Your MathJax formatting is not a thing of beauty; but your work looks ok.

Comment: @paw88789 :) thanks

Comment: The notation is wrong, for the numerator you want $\Pr((X=2)\cap ((y=0)\cup (y=1))$, but that turned out to be what you calculated.

Answer (score 1):

We want 
$$\Pr(X=2\mid (Y=0)\cup (Y=1)).$$
By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(X=2\mid (Y=0)\cup (Y=1))=\frac{\Pr(X=2\cap ((Y=0)\cup (Y=1)))}{\Pr((Y=0)\cup (Y=1))}.$$
It turns out that the numerator on the right is $0.2$, which is the number you actually used. But the post says that the numerator is $\Pr(X=2\mid ((Y=0)\cup (Y=1)))$.